# Warning: got packets out of order. Expected 2 but received 0

Tags: node.js, socket.io, node-mysql2

I have made as realtime Node.js application.I am using mysql2 database.

`Server start with:- pm2 start app`

The next day, my server is not responding. And I got this error

`Warning: got packets out of order. Expected 2 but received 0`

```
Error: Can't add new command when connection is in closed state
at Connection._addCommandClosedState 
(/var/www/html/main/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:148:17)
at Connection.query (/var/www/html/main/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:546:17)
at internal/util.js:340:30
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at Connection.query (internal/util.js:339:12)
at Object.setBattleDetails (/var/www/html/main/Models/updateScore.js:36:30)
at Socket.matchStarted (/var/www/html/main/Controllers/PlayerMatching.js:142:52)
at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) {
fatal: true
}
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: i have same issue , ```Warning: got packets out of order. Expected 2 but received 1``` but i dunno where is the error line and there is no report from users. and nothing happened on server.